# How to exact differentiate python and snake article by machine?

Tags: python, semantics

I try to create a python language news aggregate site http://www.pythonmeme.com like planet, I crawled python news from social media like G+ and twitter and some python feed by some python keywords.

But some articles about snake on resultsand I found its difficult to exact identify these articles about snake, I create a dict to filter it, but its not good enough.

Is there a better method to do this?

```
snack_dic = ['shoe', 'snake', 'nail', 'python hunter']

def is_snake(txt):
    for dic in snack_dic:
        if re.search(dic, txt, re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: I really don't understand your question.

Comment: @senderle: I think what he's asking is how to differentiate between posts about a certain programming language and posts about snakes.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the general gist. But that's still too vague to be a meaningful question.

Comment: Sorry for my bad description and I'll try to update to make it clear

Answer (score 0):

look for other programming-related words in the post: "syntax", "error", "program", "programming", "script"; you won't likely find these words in a post about snakes. (credit to duskwuff for clarifying question)

Comment: Good point, but in this case, most of articles is about python programming language, less is about snake, maybe only 5-10%. And I think create a programming-relate words dict have same issue with  create snake filter dict

Answer (score 0):

You might try using a naive Bayes classifier. Since you're interested in Python, spambayes might already be familiar to you. You'd need to hand classify a bunch of articles, with article about the snake (or the comedy group) as "spam" and those about the programming language as "ham."